# How to show a grid based on previous window button click WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button `button UpdatePatient` on the window `MainMenuWindow`. What I want the button to do is display the `PatientMainWindow` as well as the grid on the `PatientMainWindow` and change the label content to `Update Patient`.

```
private void button_updatePatient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        gridHidden_True();
        PatientMainWindow patientMainWindow = new PatientMainWindow();
        patientMainWindow.ShowDialog();
        patientMainWindow.Grid_SelectPatient.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        patientMainWindow.label_PatientWindowType.Content = "Update Patient";
        this.Close();
}
```

`gridHidden_True()` is just a method that I have that hides grids on the current window.

When the new window displays the label content does not change and the grid is not set to visible.

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying modal window first and only then setting properties (after window is closed). You should set them first:

```
var patientMainWindow = new PatientMainWindow();
patientMainWindow.Grid_SelectPatient.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
patientMainWindow.label_PatientWindowType.Content = "Update Patient";    
patientMainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, cant believe I didn't see that. Works fine now